# Dynamic Table using Ajax and JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter

I have this response from my json_encode

```
[{"name":"Client Serv","Handled":"1","Resolved":"1","Escalated":"0"},
 {"name":"Chat","Handled":"1","Resolved":"0","Escalated":"0"}]
```

I wanted this data to be tabulated in a table however, I think there's something wrong with my code. The append thing did not work.

```
request.done(function(msg) {
    $("#my_progress tbody").html('');
    msg = JSON.parse(msg);
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++){
        $('#my_progress tbody').append('<tr><td>' + msg[i].name +'</td><td>' + msg[i].Handled + '</td><td>' + msg[i].Resolved + '</td><td>' + msg[i].Escalated + '</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the correct JSON-string was successfully passed in your request.done function before you parse it into javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me..look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNTMQ/2/).

So your problem seems to be somewhere else. Are you sure `request.done` is called?

Open the javascript console in browser and look for errors!

Answer (score 0):

You may have a dataType (or other) error in jQuery ajax method. So done method won't call it's function parameter. If you can copy and paste of your full ajax method it would be good.

Answer (score 0):

There was an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in this line msg = JSON.parse(msg);

here is my full ajax method,

```
get_hourly_progress: function(o){


        var request = $.ajax({
              url: Logger.baseurl +Logger.indexpage+ "cs/get_hourly_progress",
              type: "POST",
              data: { 'end_date': $('#time_interval').val()},
              dataType: "html",
              beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){

              }
            });


            request.done(function(msg) {
                $("#my_progress tbody").html('');
                msg = JSON.parse(msg);
                for(i=0;i<msg.length;i++){  
                    $('#my_progress tbody').append('<tr><td>' + msg[i].name +'</td><td>' + msg[i].Handled + '</td><td>' + msg[i].Resolved + '</td><td>' + msg[i].Escalated + '</td></tr>');
                }
            }); 


            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });

},
```